# Closed representation of this integral

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, integration

I was wondering whether there is some easy closed representation for $\int_R^{\infty} e^{-k(r-R)}r^{l+1} dr$, where $l\in \mathbb{N_0}$ $k>0$ and $R>0$.

Comment: You can have a closed form in terms of the upper incomplete gamma function.

Comment: have never heard about it, but can you write it down?

Comment: Ok, I'll do that.

Comment: The command of Maple $$ int(exp(-k*(r-R))*r^{l+1}, r = R .. infinity)\, assuming k > 0, R > 0, l::posint$$  produces       $${\frac {{{\rm e}^{kR}}\Gamma  \left( l+2,kR \right) }{{k}^{l}{k}^{2}}} .$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral is $$I=\int_{R}^{\infty}e^{-k(r-R)}r^{l+1}dr=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-kr}(r+R)^{l+1}dr=\sum_{j=0}^{l+1}\binom{l+1}{j}R^{l+1-j}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-kr}r^j\ dr\\
=\sum_{j=0}^{l+1}\binom{l+1}{j}R^{l+1-j}\frac{\Gamma\left(j+1\right)}{k^{j+1}}\\
=\frac{(l+1)!}{k^{l+2}}\sum_{n=0}^{l+1}\frac{(Rk)^n}{n!}\\
= \frac{(l+1)!}{k^{l+2}}S_{l+1}(Rk)$$ where $\displaystyle S_n(x):=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{x^n}{n!}$

Comment: this is actually cool

Answer (score 1):

$$ I=\int_R^{\infty} e^{-k(r-R)}r^{l+1} dr= e^{kR}\int_R^{\infty} e^{-kr}r^{l+1} dr. $$

Now, using the change of variables $kr=t$ gives

$$ = e^{kR}\int_R^{\infty} e^{-kr}r^{l+1} dr = \frac{e^{kR}}{k^{l+2}}\int_{Rk}^{\infty} e^{-t}t^{l+1} dr $$

> $$I = \frac{e^{kR}}{k^{l+2}}\Gamma( l+2, Rk ),$$

where $ \Gamma(s,x) $ is the [incomplete gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function).

Comment: @Lipschitz: You are welcome.